# I can detect workout started on backgroun with apple watch, but how can I detect workout finished?

Tags: swift, watchkit, healthkit, watchos

I can detect workout started on backgroun with apple watch, with below code

```
let workoutevent =  HKObjectType.workoutType()

 if store.authorizationStatus(for: workoutevent) != HKAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined {
            store.enableBackgroundDelivery(for: workoutevent, frequency: .immediate, withCompletion: { (worked, error) in
                print(worked)
                print(error)
                print("workoutevent enableBackgroundDelivery")
                guard worked else {
                    self.logger.error("Unable to set up background delivery from HealthKit: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    print("workoutevent unable to set up background ")
                    fatalError()
                }
                if error != nil {
                    print("workoutevent error is ")
                    print(error)
                }
            })


            backgroundObserver3 =
            HKObserverQuery(sampleType: workoutevent,
                            predicate: nil,
                            updateHandler: processUpdate3(query:completionHandler3:error:))
            if let queryworkout = backgroundObserver3 {
                print("Starting  workoutevent333 the background observer query.\(queryworkout)")
                store.execute(queryworkout)
            }

        }else{
            print("not determined....")
        }
```

whenever I started workout on apple watch, it goes to
processUpdate3
very well,
but what I need to know is to when user finish workout.
how can I detect it ?

```
func processUpdate3(query: HKObserverQuery,
                       completionHandler3: @escaping () -> Void,
                       error: Error?) {
        print("come here when work out started ")
```

...........
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see it in your code. But somewhere you must have an `HKWorkoutSession`. My app is set up to track running and I configure the session to begin like so;

```
    let configuration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
    configuration.activityType = .running

    do {
        // HKWorkoutSession is set up here.
        session = try HKWorkoutSession(healthStore: healthStore, configuration: configuration)
        workoutBuilder = session.associatedWorkoutBuilder()
    } catch {
        // handle errors
    }
```

When the users taps the end workout button I call `session.end()`

Here is a [link to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutsession/2962932-end).